# Парсинг json-строки из блока success ajax-запроса

Tags: jquery

Делаю парс json-строки:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: parser + ip,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        //var country = $.parseJSON('"country_code"');
        //console.log(country);
    }
});
```

и получаю следующую строку: `{"country_code":"RU"}`. Как мне вытащить из json-строки значение поля **country_code**?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
dataType: 'json',
url: parser + ip,
success: function(data){
    var data = JSON.parse(data);// Преобразует строку в объект
    console.log(data.country_code);// Вытаскиваем значение свойства объекта
}
});
```

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: Какой парсинг? Тип ответа `json`, `jQuery` сама попытается распарсить ответ.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 Если такая ошибка - значит в data приходит строка не такого типа :{"country_code":"RU"}

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что использовать парсинговые функции не нужно.

```
var parsed = data.country_code;
```